# REST resources with a triple as a parameter

Tags: http, rest, url-design

When needing to create a URL that takes a finite set of parameters, where all of said parameters are semantically the same "level", what is the current consensus around the use of delimiters within URLs? Here's an example:

```
/myresource/thing1,thing2,thing3
/myresource/thing2,thing1
/myresource/thing1;thing2;thing3
/myresource/thing1;thing3
```

That is to say, the parameter here could be a single, a pair or a triple. They can be specified in any order because they are not a logical tree, and thing2 is not a subordinate resource of thing1, so doing something like this seems "wrong":

```
/myresources/thing1/thing2/thing3
```

This bothers me because it implies a tree-like relationship between the elements of the triple, and that is not the case (despite many HTTP frameworks seemingly pushing this, wrongly in my view). In addition, using a query string doesn't feel right as this is not a search operation, it is a known triple in a very finite space - there's nothing to query or search, so to speak.

I suppose the other option would be to make it a `POST` request and supply a body that details the parts of the triple being supplied. This doesn't give me warm fuzzies though, for some reason.

How have others handled this? Delimiters seem clean to me, and communicate the intended semantics of the resource, but i know there are folks would would take a different view, and I was looking to understand the experiences of others who've had similar use cases.

Comment: What are these parameters? Can you write them as key-value-pairs like `thing1=value1`?

Answer (score 0):

Since any value can be missing and values can appear in any order, How would you know which value is for which parameter (if that matters).

I would have used query string for GET, or in the payload for POST.

Comment: It doesn't actually matter - its an unordered triple :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use query parameters

```
/path/to/the/resource?key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3
```

or matrix parameters

```
/path/to/the/resource;key1=value1;key2=value2;key3=value3
```

Comment: Agreed - these seem like the only decent options. Matrix params are still not an official thing it seems though, as they only appear in a document marked as "personal view" by Tim BL. Choices, choices!

Answer (score 0):

Without a proper example, I'm not sure exactly about your needs.

However, a little known fact is that any HTTP parameter can have multiple values. It is the way to go when you have a set of objects (see [GoogleMaps static API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) for an example).

```
/path/to/the/resource?things=thing1&things=thing2&things=thing3
```

Then you can use the same API for single, pairs, triples (and more).